# Django filter by serializer method field

Tags: python, django, api

I cant create some logic(for me it interesting). For example i have View like this:

```
class DucktList(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = DuckSerializer
filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('test_field',) // i want to create some custom field and filter by it if needed.
```

serializer:

```
class DuckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    test_field = SerializerMethodField() // i want filter by this field! 

    def get_test_field(self, obj):
        return True

class Meta:
    ......
```

How i can filter `filter_fields` with `test_field` ?

Comment: You can't filter the queryset with some custom fields. Fields should be either a db field or an annotated field

Comment: @JPG how can I serialize with custom fields? Any suggestions?

Comment: @nesalexy did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could define your own filter with custom methods and using this library [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html):

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class EventFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    finish_on = filters.BooleanFilter(name='finish_on', method='filter_manifestation')

    begin_on = filters.BooleanFilter(name='begin_on', method='filter_manifestation')

    def filter_manifestation(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value is False:
            lookup = '__'.join([name, 'gte'])
        else:
            lookup = '__'.join([name, 'lte'])
        qs = queryset.filter(**{lookup: timezone.now()})
        return qs

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            'finished', 'has_begun'
        ]
```

And add this filter to your view:

```
class ManifestationViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    ...
    filter_class = EventFilter
    ...
```

You could then adapt your filter's customs methods depending on what you want to do in the related function of your serializer custom field.

You have some snippets on the django-filter library doc about various filters types.